# Search functionality using Selenium

Tags: .net

How to search 100 keyword using selenium web driver?

If user wants to enter 100 keywords in each time.

Like...

jomashop,
Salvation army,
Red cross,
World vision,
roofing,
Smile train,
movers,
American red cross,
plumbers,
goodwill
American cancer society
Cash call,
united way,
electrician,
Doctors without borders,
Pest control,
Magic jack,
Where’s my tutor,
Just energy,
Locks of love,
Painters,
landscaping,
concrete,
vivint,
handyman,
loandepot,
windows,
case,
locksmith,
newegg,
directtv,
vemma,
loandepot.com,
heifer international,
carpet cleaning,
policeauctions.com,
so....on

Who can we achieve this..Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to search keywords using google? If yes then you can store all keywords using Array and then using appropriate loop you can search one by one.